# JAVA: Interacting ArrayLists?

Tags: java, arraylist

So, this is in a game environment. I have 2 ArrayLists, one is a party of 3 characters you own, and the other is an ArrayList of 3 enemy characters.

I have a method called combat which puts character "a" from your party and "b" from the enemy party in combat. I have this working without any problems, but when one of the characters dies in either ArrayList, the targets have to switch.

For example: 
1)Characters a, b, c Vs. Character d, e, f
2)I use my combat method so that a fights d, b fights e, and c fights f. All is well so far.
3)Character a loses and dies, now I have to make character b fight d and e, while c keeps fighting f.

Any ideas on how I could go about doing this?

Comment: Implement a list of actual enemies, and then when a dies pass that list to the next player, a FightMap class which maps every player with his actual enemies, using an id perhaps, i don't know how you implemented the players, they have an id?

Comment: what if b is not finished fighting e, and a dies, then b dies?

Comment: Hard to answer without at least a little code that shows how your combat works. You imply that the combat runs simultaneously--how? Turn-based? Concurrent threads? Do the enemy objects in the list need to persist even when they are dead? Etc.

Comment: It is turn based, sorry. I could give some code but it's somewhat lengthy and I think it'd be even harder to answer it then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just remove the dead character at the end of combat() method and then run the combat() again recursively until one of the lists is empty.

Pseudocode:

```
protected void combat(List<Character> heroes, List<Character> enemies) {
  if (heroes.isEmpty() || enemies.isEmpty()) {
    //one of the parties wins
    return;
  }

  List<Pair<Character, Character>> vs = new LinkedList<>();
  int i = 0;
  while ( i< heroes.length() && i< enemies.length()) {
   vs.add(heroes.get(i), enemies.get(i));
   ++i;
  }
  for (Pair<Character, Character> fight : vs) {
   //figure out the loser
   Character loser = fight(vs.getFirst(), vs.getSecond();
   if (loser.isEnemy()) {
     enemies.remove(loser);
   } else {
      heroes.remove(loser);
   }
  }
  combat(heroes, enemies);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

List friends = new ArrayList();
List enemies = new ArrayList();

// populate the lists.

// map the opponents to each other.

//if elementA in friend dies while fighting elementX

friends.remove("elementA");

//during fighting

if(friends.size()>0){
//new enemy of element X is
friends.get(1);
}
else{
//enemies has won over friends.
}